# InfoPath - not bind one field in a form to sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-2013, infopath

I have a InfoPath form that binds to a list in a SharePoint site. Because of privacy reason, I want to make sure there are few fields in a form that just used to input data (for flow control) and not stored in SharePoint list when form is stored. Is it feasible to do it? One option is to clear those fields on submit but I was wondering if its possible to not bind those fields to a list. Right now I don't see any option to do it. Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Forget workarounds like "clearing fields on submit". You never know when they will stab you in the back.

You should be able to easily map the fields and bind/unbind as needed following the info here : [InfoPath Fields Mapping - StackExchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54378/how-can-i-add-fields-from-an-infopath-form-to-a-list)